# p:socket onmessage not triggering

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I currently have my project setup setup with the Primefaces push system.

This is my socket in my xhtml:

```
<p:socket onMessage="doAction" channel="/votingStopChannel" />

<script>

    function doAction()
    {

    }
</script>
```

This should trigger as soon as I send something through the registered channel.

This is how I do that:

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
eventBus.publish("/votingStopChannel");
```

Note that I am not sending data but rather only a signal. I tried to make it work with data as well, though.

As soon as I publish the data, I do get a signal to my `Pushendpoint` class, but I never get to execute the Javascript.

I am currently doing this along to the Primefaces showcase tutorial.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What showcase tutorial? There is no oncomplete on the `p:socket` according to the documentation. Use 'onmessage'

Comment: @Kukeltje Sorry, onMessage is what I meant. I was refering to http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/counter.jsf

Comment: Take goooood look at the example. The signature of your function is wrong

Comment: @Kukeltje I tried adding the data to the JS function, but it doesn't help. If you are refering to the .publish, I also got a channel with a second parameter and actual data, but it is also not triggering its connected function

Comment: Did you debug network traffic?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it. I will answer this question with the solution! Thanks for your hint though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple.

The `onMessage()` function in your `@PushEndpoint` has to return something.

In my case, changing it from

```
public void onMessage()
{               
}
```

to

```
public boolean onMessage()
{               
    return true;
}
```

fixed my problem.

If the method does not return anything, the socket will not recognise it.